# Integration of forms over a smooth orientable manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Why does one needs to assume that a $n$-form has a compact support to be able to define its integration over a orientable $n$-manifold?

I'm referring to the following text: 
ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/cis610/public_html/diffgeom4.pdf

Comment: It is not necessary. It just simplifies things quite a bit!

Comment: Can you elaborate on that point?

Comment: If you define the integral through a partition of unity (as your text does), you need to make sure that you use only a finite number of open sets. This is easy if either the manifold is compact, or if the support of the form is compact. 
(A set $X$ is compact if and only if for any family of open sets covering $X$ there is a finite-numbered sub-family *still* covering $X$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to compute the integral of the form $\cos(t)dt$ over the real line.